# R Programming 30 day Months

Tags: r, date

I'm currently writing a script in the R Programming Language and I've hit a snag.

I have time series data organized in a way where there are 30 days in each month for 12 months in 1 year.  However, I need the data organized in a proper 365 days in a year calendar, as in 30 days in a month, 31 days in a month, etc.

Is there a simple way for R to recognize there are 30 days in a month and to operate within that parameter?  At the moment I have my script converting the number of days from the source in UNIX time and it counts up.

For example:

```
startingdate <- "20060101"
endingdate <- "20121230"
date <- seq(from = as.Date(startingdate, "%Y%m%d"), to = as.Date(endingdate, "%Y%m%d"), by = "days")
```

This would generate an array of dates with each month having 29 days/30 days/31 days etc.  However, my data is currently organized as 30 days per month, regardless of 29 days or 31 days present.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify: your desired output should be a series of dates that contain 30 days for each month regardless of this being the actual number?

Comment: In addition to G. Grothendieck's answer below, note that you can always subset a date vector. For instance, `substr(your_date, 6,7)` will give you the days. Using `which(as.numeric(substr(your_date, 6,7))<31` to subset your initial dates, you would get rid of the 31st days, and you could use the difference in days to find where you have to insert a 30th day. But the answer below using `expand.grid`is much better.

Comment: Howdy, yeah at the moment simply creating an array with the output being the 30 days per month would be fine.  Originally I was using this script for data with the proper dates done.  However I'm hacking it to work with the 30 days and I was hoping there'd be a much easier approach to it rather than what I was originally thinking, which was to simply create multiple loops to manually count up to 30 then reset, have that count up the months, then years, etc (which I think would be overengineering the problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first 4 solutions are basically variations of the same theme using `expand.grid`.  (3) uses magrittr and the others use no packages.  The last two work by creating long sequence of numbers and then picking out the ones that have month and day in range.

**1) apply** This gives a series of yyyymmdd numbers such that there are 30 days in each month.  Note that the line defining `yrs` in this case is the same as `yrs <- 2006:2012` so if the years are handy we could shorten that line. Omit `as.numeric` in the line defining `s` if you want character string output instead.   Also, `s` and `d` are the same because we have whole years so we could omit the line defining `d` and use `s` as the answer in this case and also in general if we are always dealing with whole years.

```
startingdate <- "20060101"
endingdate <- "20121230"

yrs <- seq(as.numeric(substr(startingdate, 1, 4)), as.numeric(substr(endingdate, 1, 4)))

g <- expand.grid(yrs, sprintf("%02d", 1:12), sprintf("%02d", 1:30))
s <- sort(as.numeric(apply(g, 1, paste, collapse = "")))

d <- s[ s >= startingdate & s <= endingdate ] # optional if whole years
```

Run some checks.

```
head(d)
## [1] 20060101 20060102 20060103 20060104 20060105 20060106
tail(d)
##  20121225 20121226 20121227 20121228 20121229 20121230

length(d) == length(2006:2012) * 12 * 30
## [1] TRUE
```

**2) no apply** An alternative variation would be this. In this and the following solutions we are using `yrs` as calculated in (1) so we omit it to avoid redundancy.  Also, in this and the following solutions, the corresponding line to the one setting `d` is omitted, again, to avoid redundancy -- if you don't have whole years then add the line defining `d` in (1) replacing `s` in that line with `s2`.

```
g2 <- expand.grid(yr = yrs, mon = sprintf("%02d", 1:12), day = sprintf("%02d", 1:30))
s2 <- with(g2, sort(as.numeric(paste0(yr, mon, day))))
```

**3) magrittr** This could also be written using magrittr like this:

```
library(magrittr)

expand.grid(yr = yrs, mon = sprintf("%02d", 1:12), day = sprintf("%02d", 1:30)) %>%
  with(paste0(yr, mon, day)) %>%
  as.numeric %>%
  sort -> s3
```

**4) do.call** Another variation.

```
g4 <- expand.grid(yrs, 1:12, 1:30)
s4 <- sort(as.numeric(do.call("sprintf", c("%d%02d%02d", g4))))
```

**5) subset sequence**  Create a sequence of numbers from the starting date to the ending date and if each number is of the form yyyymmdd pick out those for which mm and dd are in range.

```
seq5 <- seq(as.numeric(startingdate), as.numeric(endingdate))
d5 <- seq5[ seq5 %/% 100 %% 100 %in% 1:12 & seq5 %% 100 %in% 1:30]
```

**6) grep** Using `seq5` from (5)

```
d6 <- as.numeric(grep("(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)$", seq5, value = TRUE))
```

Comment: Wow that's lovely.  Thank you!  Yeah my original thought was simply to create multiple for loops and setting up a counter, but I'd figure there must have been an easier way.  Thanks for showing multiple ways to do this as well!  As I can totally learn more about R from this.  Seriously, I'm absolutely stoaked from your answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative:

```
date <- unclass(startingdate):unclass(endingdate) %% 30L
month <- rep(1:12, each = 30, length.out = NN <- length(date))
year <- rep(1:(NN %/% 360 + 1), each = 360, length.out = NN)
```

(of course, we can easily adjust by adding constants to taste if you want a specific day to be 0, or a specific month, etc.)

Comment: That's lovely thank you!  Again, something much easier than what I was originally thinking, which was a bunch of for loops.